# Entity Framework MySQL DbContext cannot connect

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, dbcontext

I created a models using code-first and without storing password in App.config, I passing it in constructor of DbContext instead:

```
public TasksWithoutPasswordContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
{
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;
}
```

But I got a runtime error while trying to get DbSet of my DbContext:

```
using (TasksWithoutPasswordContext contextWithoutPassword = new TasksWithoutPasswordContext(connectionString))
{
    foreach (var user in contextWithoutPassword.users)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(user.user);
    }
}
```

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server).

I tried to mark my class as next:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class TasksWithoutPasswordContext : DbContext
```

and it didn't helped.

Comment: can you show us your connectionstring? mark your password with ****

Comment: have you done what error asked you? have you checked if this is correct connection string and your server is running?

Comment: @Matthias Burger, server=localhost;user id=test_user1;password=****;database=tasks_for_consultants

Comment: is it mysql you are using? maybe try with another connectionstring: `Server=localhost;Database=tasks_for_consultants;Uid=test_user1;Pwd=****`

Comment: @Andrey Ischencko, yes of course, I can open my db in phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench

Comment: Possibly you need to add the port to your connectionstring:
`Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=tasks_for_consultants;Uid=test_use‌​r1;Pwd=****` you started a server to use your mysql-database with? xampp for example?

Comment: @Matthias Burger, something wrong in DbProviderFactory: https://ibb.co/gxxpuQ

Comment: what is wrong? Don't see a problem :/

Comment: Did you debug and check that `nameOrConnectionString` has correct connection string?

Comment: @Chetan Ranpariya, yes, I pass the correct connection string, because I can connect to database with MySqlConnection class using ths connection string

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, the wrong is that `this.Database.Connection.DbProviderFactory = {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory}`, but should be `this.Database.Connection.DbProviderFactory = {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory}`

Comment: Ah okay. So what type is your DbContext from (Whole namespace)?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, 
`[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
TasksForConsultants.Database.Models.WithoutPassword.TasksWithoutPasswordContext : DbContext`

Comment: Okay. Where did you add your connection string? in the web-config? If yes, could you copy/paste it here? :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, I create the connection string at runtime using `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: okay, I got it myself. there should be no parameter in base constructor of DbContext: `public TasksWithoutPasswordContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base()
        {
            this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;
        }`

Comment: So does it work now?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, yes it is.

Comment: Write an answer so other users with the same issue can get it solved :)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger, how can I anser my own question? could you tell please

Comment: ah maybe you can't because of too less reputation. I write one for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already found the solution yourself, I add the answer:

When you're inheriting from DbContext and call the base constructor, you could use the default-base-constructor (the parameterless one) and set the connectionstring in constructor:

```
public TasksWithoutPasswordContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base() 
{
    this.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = nameOrConnectionString;
}
```